# Pass bitmap Uri to a fragment of another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, fragment, uri

I have two Activities, A and B. I start B from a fragment of A, called F. I have a bitmap object in B. I need to pass the Uri of this bitmap to F. Here is sample code,
This code is in F:

```
Intent bIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
startActivityForResult(bIntent , 111);
```

This code is in B:

```
Intent aIntent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
aIntent.putExtra("image", uri);
setResult(RESULT_OK, aIntent);
finish();
```

Again this code is in F:

```
if(requestCode == 111 && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Uri path = (Uri) extras.get("image");
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myImage);
            iv.setImageURI(path);
        }            
}
```

But it doesn't work. I need the correct code in general and in this particular case.

Comment: you are passing the wrong intent object to setresult

Answer (score 3):

By default Android Uri class extends parcelable interface. You can take the inserted Uri with getParcelableExtra method like this:

```
Uri path = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");
if(path != null) {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    iv.setImageURI(path);
}
```

Or in your own way:

```
Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Uri path = (Uri) extras.getParcelable("image");
            if(path != null) {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myImage);
                iv.setImageURI(path);
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Try to call iv.invalidate after you reset the image as such:

```
Uri path = result.getParcelableExtra("image");
    if(path != null) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        iv.setImageURI(path);
        iv.invalidate();
    }
```

EDIT2: I just realise that there is a mistake in Activity B. Try to change and make sure you are using intent result which is parameter of onActivityResult instead of GetActivity

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, editIntent);
```

to

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, aIntent);
```

Comment: Hello, can you try to call iv.invalidate() after you set up your image?

Comment: Hi Orkun, Thank you for answer. but It seems (path != null ) condition returns false !

Comment: That is not really an issue. The code above is just a demo. I correct it. The real issue is why Nothing pass to the fragment? Why 'path' is null?

Comment: Can I define a global variable to pass data between activities instead of putExtra and Bundle ?

Comment: You can do that with a String which points to path of the uri and recreate it within activites.